# Axios Response Data Replace

Tags: vue.js, axios, twitch, twitch-api

I'm trying to learn Axios and Vue with using Twitch API. I'm fetching data from that API and there is *thumbnail_url* which is for channel's thumbnail photos but I have to change that data's **width** and **height** because it's coming like this;

```
https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_shroud-{width}x{height}.jpg
```

And I was trying to do like this;

```
beforeMount(){
  helix.get('streams?language=en').then((response) => {
    for(var i=0; i < response.data.data.length; i++){
      response.data.data[i].thumbnail_url.replace("width", "40")
    }
    console.log(response.data.data)
  this.results = response.data.data
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
     console.log(error);
     });
},
```

Actually, I didn't understand what that is not working. I know there is a point that I missed. If someone can help me, It'd be great.
And If It is not correct way to do this, what is the correct way?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which part do you think is not working? Are you not getting the data in the response or are you not able to replace the `width`?

Comment: After that code when I check the console log or output, it's still looking same. Width string is not changing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `replace("{width}", "40");` instead

```js
var url = 'https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_shroud-{width}x{height}.jpg';
url = url.replace("{width}", "40");
url = url.replace("{height}", "60");
console.log(url);
```

In your code change this

```
var thumbnail_url = response.data.data[i].thumbnail_url;
thumbnail_url = thumbnail_url.replace("{width}", "40");
thumbnail_url = thumbnail_url.replace("{height}", "60");
response.data.data[i].thumbnail_url = thumbnail_url;
```

As you comment you can do it without variable also

```
response.data.data[i].thumbnail_url = response.data.data[i].thumbnail_url.replace("{width}", "40").replace("{height}", "60");
```

Comment: I see but that url is not same all the time. I'm fetching data for too much channels and every channel has their own thumbnail url.

Comment: ok, then share that all info in your question, I will try to change my answer accordingly then. @lilrevo share other ulr format for thumbnail if you have ?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/my8rol here is the console log of the result that i am fetching. I have to change width and height for all of them when i'm fetching data. But I couldn't find the solution

Comment: @lilrevo : I have added code, according to your vuejs code.

Comment: It is worked. Thanks a lot. Should I use variable all the time when I want to do some changes?

Comment: @lilrevo : you can do it without variable but using var is good practice, have shared other code also.